# implementing Azure Application Security Group using Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

The Application Security Group feature was just released in April. We are trying to implement this since we have large number of servers so the Network Security Group can quickly become hard to manage.

I cannot find any example Terraform code for this. I've modified the example Terraform code from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/terraform-create-complete-vm for a quick POC. The scenario is we have a group of bastion servers (for now just 1) that we secure and all SSH into important servers will come from these bastion servers. So I've created a bastion_asg Application Security Group and have setup the DL2staging_rtb_nsg to only allow servers from bastion_asg for SSH access. However, once it ran and created the servers, I was not able to ssh into DL2staging_rtb_vm. I've attached my code.

Would really appreciate any and all pointers as to what might be wrong with my POC.

Thanks,

Derek

** Here is the main code addition to the sample Terraform code from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/terraform-create-complete-vm:

```
resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "DL2staging_rtb_nsg" {
...

security_rule {
  name                        = "AllowSSHInbound"
  ...
  source_application_security_group_ids = ["${azurerm_application_security_group.bastion_asg.id}"]
  destination_address_prefix  = "*"
}

# Create network interface
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "DL2staging_rtb_nic" {
...

ip_configuration {
    name                          = "DL2NicConfiguration"
    ...
    application_security_group_ids = ["${azurerm_application_security_group.staging_sellsidertb_asg.id}"]
}
```

The complete code is at https://github.com/dl888888/azure-terraform-application-security-group/blob/master/vm3.tf

Comment: If the answer is helpful or for more help, please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that my code works. The problem I was having is assuming that the ASG (Application Security Group) would work with the public ip addresses of the VMs that I have. I found out with Azure Product Managers that ASG only work with the private ip addresses. This is a big ommission from the ASG documenation.

Derek

Answer (score 0):

As I see, you associate an NSG and an ASG with each network interface, and just allow the traffic through the ASG, not NSG.

I suggest you should read the document [Application security groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/security-overview#application-security-groups) again, and I think the example of it makes a good Network Architecture.

For your issue, I suggest one NSG with the Subnet and one ASG associated to each network interface. Then allow the traffic with clearly source and destination, in Terraform it means clearly `source_application_security_group_ids` and `destination_application_security_group_ids`.